# Android10 Clean Architecture: почему используются исключительно фрагменты?

Tags: android

Разбираюсь с clean architecture на примере [android10/Android-CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin). Насколько я вижу, в этом проекте нет ни одного активити использующего setContentView и работающего с вью. Каждое активити в этом проекте содержит в себе фрагмент, и вся работа с вью осуществляется в этом фрагменте. Почему так сделано? В чем смысл этого? Почему активити не работают с разметкой напрямую, а делают это через дополнительную сущность в виде фрагмента?

Answer (score 2):

Если ваше приложение работает только на смартфонах, то можно обойтись только активностью(Activity) и ее макетом(layout), однако некоторые авторы рекомендуют сразу использовать Фрагменты(Fragment). Причины использования Фрагментов сформулированы в https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.

> Фрагмент может использоваться как часть макета(layout) вашего приложения, позволяя лучше разделять код на модули и легче настраивать пользовательский интерфейс под экран, на котором запущенно ваше приложение

Для пояснения идеи, можно привести классически пример приложение вида "список-детализация".

Вариант приложения для телефона без использования фрагментов  будет состоять из двух активностей и их макетов. Активность будет заполнять макет и выводить его на экран через setContentView(), получать ссылки на объекты Вью(View) через findViewById() и затем работать с полученнами ссылками. Но если вам **ВНЕЗАПНО** понадобится адаптировать приложение под большой экран прланшета, где удобно разместить  список и детализацию на одном экране, то сразу возникнут некоторые неудобства:

1. Придется  создать новый макет для планшета, который содержит ТЕ
   ЖЕ САМЫЕ элементы, которые содержатся в уже созданных для телефона
   макетах
2. В коде активност нужно учесть, что активность может
   содержать разное кол-во представлений, в зависимости от типа
   устройства.

Теперь расмотрим аналогичное приложение при использовании фрагментов.

Фрагменты, хоть и располагаются внутри активностей, могу иметь свои собственные макеты и имеют свой собственный жизненый цикл, т.е. являются отдельными частями пользовательского интерфейса и поведения. Например один фрагмент отвечает(заполнение представлений на основе макета, получение ссылок на представления, работа с представлениями и т.д.) за список, другой - за детализацию. В варианте приложения для телефона, активность хост должна только размещать в себе фрагмент и заменять один фрагмент другим, при переходе от списка к детализации, ничег "не зная" о внутреннем устройстве фрагмент.  Все аспекты инкапсулированы внутри фрагмента. При необходимости адаптации приложения для планшета, изменить макет активности, для одновременного размещения двух фрагментов, и модифицировать код активности с учетом этого. Но т.к. сами фрагменты являются отдельными частями, их изменения не потребуется. Количество изменений значительно меньше по сравнению с первым вариантом, где используются только активности.

Еще, как отметили выше, в фрагменте можно вызвать `setRetainInstance(true)` для сохранения экземпляра фрагмента при уничтожении активности хоста (соответственно "данные не сбросятся"). Но удерживание фрагмента - спорное решение проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Activity представляет собой экран приложения. Фрагмент, как следует из названия, представляет собой часть экрана. На том же планшете можно разместить рядом два фрагмента, какие на смартфоне, с меньшим размером дисплея, занимают по экрану.

Comment: А есть ли в этом какой-то смысл с точки зрения Clean Architecture? Если мое приложение будет работать только на смартфонах и активити мне в принципе достаточно?

Comment: С точки зрения CA разницы никакой. То и то - View

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что это вызвана возможность переиспользовать фрагмент, например, отобразить в activity два фрагмента рядом (для планшетной версии). Кроме того, я слышал, что при переворачивании экрана, activity сбрасывает данные, а fragment нет (или у фрагмента есть возможность их сохранить, точно не скажу, ибо не проверял)